# Return index of multiple highest scores

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on an idea of how to return the index of the highest scores from an array, but I'm struggling to figure out if I could return multiple items from this method, or whether I would need to use an alternative method to return the index of two highest scores in an array.

```
 var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54,
                  58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69,
                  34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51,
                  69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61,
                  46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
                  41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];

var tests = scores.length;
var highest;
for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    highest = scores[i];
  }
  if (scores[i] > highest) {
    highest = scores[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: `scores.slice().sort().filter(function(v, i, a) {
  return a.indexOf(v) === i;
}).slice(-2);`

Comment: @Vohuman returns `[66,69]`, which are highest unique scores, but as I read the question I believe OP wants to find all the indexes of `69` (which is the highest but appears twice). EDIT: now that I read again I think I may have misunderstood.

Comment: The question is not very clear, that's why I haven't posted an answer. As OP stores the _highest value_ and not the _index of the highest value_ in the posted code snippet I have suggested that snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Return an array containing the indexes. When you get an element higher than the highest, empty the array and put i into it. When you get an element equal to the highest, push i onto the array.

```
var highest = scores[0];
var indexes = [0];
for (var i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] > highest) {
        // Found new highest, reset everything
        indexes = [i];
        highest = scores[i];
    } else if (scores[i] == highest) {
        // Found duplicate highest, add its index to indexes array
        indexes.push(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// find the maximum value in an array:
var max = Math.max.apply( null, scores );  // 69
var maxindexes = [];
// iterate over the array and push the indexes of items matching the max to maxindexes
scores.forEach( function( score, idx ){
  if( score == max ){
    maxindexes.push( idx );   
  }
});  // [11,18]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/und26dep/

Comment: I don't think you should iterate twice over the array

Comment: Yeah it'll probably take like extra 2ms for 10k elements ;)

Answer (score 0):

The basic Javscript way is like this:

```
var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];

alert(getHighestIndexes(scores));    

function getHighestIndexes(scores)
{
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) 
    {
        if (i == 0)             
            result.push(scores[i]);                         
        else if (scores[i] > result[0])                     
            result = [i];                   
        else if (scores[i] == result[0])        
            result.push(i);         
    }
    return result;
}
```

But best practice is to use a functional library like lodash or underscore js, then you can do it like this:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/3.10.1/lodash.min.js" ></script>    
<script>
    var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];  
    alert(getHighestIndexes(scores));

    function getHighestIndexes(scores)
    {
        var arrayAsObject = _.zip(scores, _.range(scores.length));
        return _.pluck(_.where(arrayAsObject , {"0" : _.max(scores)}), "1");    
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript `.sort()` function to order them from highest to lowest and then get the first 2 indexes of the array (or however many you want)

```js
var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54,
              58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69,
              34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51,
              69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61,
              46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
              41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];


var sorted = scores.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
console.log(sorted);
alert('Two Highest Scores: ' + sorted[0] + ' and ' +  sorted[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way: find max element, and then reduce source array to index of max elements, like this

```
var arr = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54,
          58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69,
          34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51,
          69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61,
          46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
          41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
var max = Math.max.apply(Math,arr);
var res = arr.reduce(function(acc,cur,index){
    if(cur==max) acc.push(index);
    return acc;
},[]);
```